# Rally iteration health Javascript error

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm interested in customizing the [Rally Iteration Health](https://github.com/kcorkan/rally-iteration-health-1).

When I grabbed the code and assumed I would proceed by using the file "app-debug-tpl.html" to test it, unmodified. I'm getting javascript error:
"Expected an operand but found <" 
on line 13:
Rally.loadScripts(<%= JSON.stringify(js_files) %>

I'm awfully confused about what's causing that error. Any help pointing me toward what I'm missing is appreciated. I've deployed the "\Deploy\app.txt" and it works, so I figure I'm missing something about setting up the development/test code.

Answer (score 0):

So, with a little help from a conversation with CA Agile Central folks, it turns out part of this was an error on my part. This app does not use the Rally App Builder. It must be built using grunt instructions on the [original readme.md from RallyTechServices](https://github.com/RallyTechServices/rally-iteration-health/blob/master/README.md).